# Screen size and dpi of bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, dpi, screen-size

I found two approximations of how developer should support bitmaps for different screen sizes. One is this:

> ldpi  low density 120 dpi
>
> mdpi  medium density  160 dpi
>
> hdpi  high density    240 dpi
>
> xhdpi extra high density  320 dpi

The other is this:

> xhdpi: 2.0
>
> hdpi: 1.5
>
> mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
>
> ldpi: 0.75
>
> > This means that if you generate a 200x200 image for xhdpi devices, you
> >     should generate the same resource in 150x150 for hdpi, 100x100 for
> >     mdpi and finally a 75x75 image for ldpi devices

Does it mean that If I take as a baseline 640x360, I have to make following 4 groups of images:

> 1) ldpi - size 480x270 pixels and density 120 dpi
>
> 2) mdpi - size 640x360 pixels and density 160 dpi
>
> 3) hdpi - size 960x540 pixels and density 240 dpi
>
> 4) xhdpi - size 1280x720 pixels and density 320 dpi

Comment: All covered in the docs. http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: You don't have to care anymore about ldpi, but should add XXHDI instead!

Comment: @Kuffs As I said in the question the documentation says 2 different things at different points. One about bitmap dpi and one about the bitmap size. I have read the documentation, otherwise where I would get the quote I gave in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding.

The documentation is not saying different things. The second part you reference is telling you how much bigger an image is in relation to the base density of mdpi

e.g xhdpi fits 2x the amount of horizontal and vertical pixels into the same space that mdpi would.

mdpi = 160 dpi (scale factor 1)

xhdpi = 320 dpi (x2 twice as dense as mdpi therefore an image in this folder needs to be twice as high and twice as wide as its mdpi counterpart to appear the same size on an xhdpi screen)

Comment: Sorry, I should've added quote fully. So at the end of the second reference, the documentage page(http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html) says:
"This means that if you generate a 200x200 image for xhdpi devices, you should generate the same resource in 150x150 for hdpi, 100x100 for mdpi and finally a 75x75 image for ldpi devices."
So that's actually the dimensions not dpi

Comment: Yes it refers to the height and width only. An image by itself has no concept of density. It simply is x pixels high and y pixels wide. DPI is a display parameter that indicates how many of those pixels occupy an inch.

Comment: You can adjust dpi of a picture in photoshop. So if I produce 4 groups of images I've described in the question, will it be enough and adequate?

Comment: Photoshop is misleading as it does not change the DPI. It changes the resolution. As I said, an image has no concept of density. It is always x pixels high and y pixels wide (the clue is in the name. DPI=Dots Per Inch). The density is a display parameter that controls how many pixels fit in an inch. You should justinclude the images at the correct size and android cwill display them at the correct size. If you do not include a particular density then the system will scale one of the available images up or down.